# How to allign Add to Cart buttons in WooCommerce?

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce

i have one issue with "Add To Cart" button in my [shop](http://ckdemo.celebritykids.sg/shop/). Add to cart button is missalligned, and looking very bad, so i want to make all in one line. This is CSS from that part:

```
.dark .button.is-form:hover,.button:hover,input[type='submit']:hover,input[type='reset']:hover,input[type='button']:hover {
outline: none;
opacity: 1;
color: #000;
box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 100px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
```

How to make add to cart button alligned in one row the same like image shown?[image]

Comment: hi paste the link for add to cart button on your website..

Comment: Have URL in my first post.

Answer (score 1):

You have different sizes for all the product boxes,
Fix the height of product-small,

```
.product-small{
    height: 490px;
}
```

Buttons will be auto adjusted then.

Comment: That not fixed the issue. When insert that code, i get overlappting with product image, and add to cart button is not covered by product image.

Answer (score 1):

You can download this free plugin to automatically align woocommerce add to cart buttons.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/woo-align-buttons/

The code is also available on GitHub.

https://github.com/Aquafortis/woo-align-buttons

Hope this helps.

Comment: Some additional information would probably be useful.